# New line in Sql Query

Tags: sql

How you get new line or line feed in Sql Query ?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Pinal Dave explains this well in his blog.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/01/sql-server-difference-between-line-feed-n-and-carriage-return-r-t-sql-new-line-char/

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
PRINT ('SELECT FirstLine AS FL ' + @NewLineChar + 'SELECT SecondLine AS SL')
```

Comment: Thanks nice Blog and nice information my problem solve from this

Answer (score 40):

```
-- Access: 
SELECT CHR(13) & CHR(10) 

-- SQL Server: 
SELECT CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
```

Comment: -- oracle: `CHR(13) || CHR(10)`

Answer (score 19):

You could do `Char(13)` and `Char(10)`. Cr and Lf.

`Char()` works in SQL Server, I don't know about other databases.

Answer (score 15):

use `CHAR(10)` for New Line in SQL
 `char(9)` for Tab
and `Char(13)` for Carriage Return