# In Oracle, what is the SQL to query for occurences of line feed?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the rows where a certain column contains line feed.

This does not work:
select * from [table] where [column] like '%\n%'

In SO, I found the solution for SQL Server:
[New line in Sql Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085662/new-line-in-sql-query)

But this does not work in Oracle. Is there any ANSI SQL solution? This should be a standard...

If not, what is the solution in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to InStr() that expresses the SQL a bit more in line with the problem. IMHO.

```
select * from [table] where [column] like '%'||chr(10)||'%'
```

Answer (score 3):

you could look for the CHR(10) character (the character for newline):

```
select * from [table] where instr(column, chr(10)) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Oracle 10g upwards, you could use

```
select * from [table] where regexp_like([column], '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from tableNameHere where instr(colNameHere, chr(10)) > 0

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE column LIKE "%\n%"
```

\n is line feed, \r is carriage return...