# How to enter new line using sql command INSERT

Tags: sql, newline, informix, dml

Q:

I wanna to know the syntax of SQL query of inserting new line in my table.

I mean ,I wanna to enter the following in my table `abc`:

```
  aaaaaaaaaa

  bbbbbbbbbb

  cccccccccccc
```

Maintaining the new line.through INSERT command .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually, the best way to deal with that is with a placeholder '?' in the SQL and pass the value via a host variable when the statement is executed.  This method also avoids SQL injection attacks.  Failing that, the `ifx_allow_newline()` function is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I answered this question, you'd got it tagged with SQL Server 2008.  You've since edited it to be about Informix.  The following works for SQL Server 2008.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyField) VALUES('AAAAA' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'BBBBB')
```

Informix looks more complicated.  You have to set an option according to [this documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls1078.htm) I found with a google for "informix sql newline"

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE IFX_ALLOW_NEWLINE('T')
```

Answer (score 2):

Never used informix but for SQL Server 2008 this is just.

```
INSERT INTO abc
            (col1)
VALUES (
'aaaaaaaaaa

bbbbbbbbbb

cccccccccccc');
```

Comment: mmmm , thanks this doesn't work with informix, `Found a quote for which there is no matching quote`

Comment: Someone else will have to supply the `Informix` end of things!

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyColumn) VALUES ('aaaaaaaaaa

bbbbbbbbbb

cccccccccccc');
```

Comment: mmmm , thanks this doesn't work with informix, `Found a quote for which there is no matching quote`

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you're using Windows or `*nix` conventions, but it will be some combination of `\r` and `\n`

Have a look at the [New line in Sql Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085662/new-line-in-sql-query#) question.

Comment: Good information,thanks alot .this is about how to get.but my question is about How to insert?

Answer (score 1):

why not store the row without the newline, then on the client side of your app, provide for it?